# C#: Code review for 'Contine' in catch block inside for-loop

Tags: c#

Following is my code,where I need to continue the loop in case of exception inside try block.

```
for (int i = 0; i < doc.Length; i++)
{
    name = doc[i].ToString();
    try
    {
        if (name != "")
        {
        name=name.ToString().Substring(12);
        break;
        }
    }
    catch{
        continue;
    }
}
```

Please tell me if i`m wrong at any place in my code.Please check for performance wise too.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like a candidate for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: remove `break` out of your code, it will work fine

Comment: @CuongLe:Thanks a lot.No, I have put that because I have to come out of the loop if it doesn`t throw any error. Is it a problem???

Comment: Maybe not relevant but why can't you check the string length and avoid the try...Catch? Also double .ToString would be unnecessary.

Comment: I'd say that's quite relevant

Comment: @FuleSnabel:I agree for that, but sorry still code is there further which I couldn`t put in. I got to put try..catch here.

Comment: You're asking for a code review on a public site for code you can't allow to be reviewed? and on the wrong site for that matter... Doesn't seem appropriate. +1 vote to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var name = doc.FirstOrDefault(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x) && x.Length >= 12);
```

Comment: Cuong Le : I didn`t know stuffs like such. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @user2002774: Now you already know :)

Answer (score 2):

The `continue` is unneeded.  It will automatically continue.

Comment: Dan-o : Really??? If so then i`ll remove it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need exception handling if you can avoid it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < doc.Length; i++)
{
    name = doc[i].ToString();

    if(name != null && name.Length >= 12)
    {    
        name = name.Substring(12);    
        break;
    }
}
```

Never use exceptions for something that is not exceptional. If you don't expect any of documents will have length less that 12, then you can use exceptions (but also not just for control flow):

```
for (int i = 0; i < doc.Length; i++)
{
    name = doc[i].ToString();

    if (name.Length < 12)
        throw new FooException("Wrong document found!");

    // do something with name
}
```

Comment: You don't even need the `name != ""`

Comment: @McAden agree, code will stay same in this case. But I'd added null check also

Comment: You can probably skip the `name != null` as well since it's initialized from a ToString(). I've never seen ToString return null

Comment: @McAden sorry, I can't until I see `ToString()` implementation of `doc` :)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need break or continue here.
try this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < doc.Length; i++)
{
    name = doc[i].ToString();

    try
    {
        if (!string.IsNotNullOrEmpty(name))
        {
            name=name.ToString().Substring(12);
        }
    }
    catch{ } 
}
```